# Trying to display results of a sum query in TMemo

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm trying to display the result of an `SQL SUM query` on a **Price** field(containing prices) grouping the results by month from a **Date**(`timestamp` field) and also using a `WHERE` clause that displays only the results containing a certain word (in this case **Folio**) contained in another field, to a `TMemo`

Consequently my query looks like this:

```
select date_format(data, '%M-%Y'), sum(pret) as test from arhivalux where statistica='Folio' group by statistica, year(data), month(data)
```

When I run this in **phpMyAdmin** to test it, it returns the following:

[image]

The results correspond to the months November, December, January and February - since I have entries in the database only for those months, so the query works.

In Delphi, testing this with the following code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Query.Close;
 Query.SQL.Text := ('select date_format(data, ''%M-%Y''), sum(pret) as test from arhivalux where statistica=''Folio'' group by statistica, year(data), month(data)');
 Query.Open;
 Memo1.Lines.Text := Query.FieldByName('test').AsString;

end;
```

It works but only displays the first value, **11679** not all 4 and no Y/M in front of the value. 
First time trying this so I must be missing something

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: valid SQL need any cols in GROUP BY also in SELECT, though MySQL do not complain. But you should say: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(...), SUM(pret) ...

Comment: @SIDU thanks, updated my question - it still doesn't display all the values in Memo1, like phpmyadmin does

Comment: BTW, why are you grouping results by `statistica` when all of the results will have the same `statistica` value?  You should be able to group by just the dates

Comment: @RemyLebeau Statistica contains 3 values, UV - Folio and Promo. Every new order that comes in gets assigned to one of these. At the end of the month I would run this query
so I could see the total amount of money (sum) each machine produced, per month/year. I plan to execute a query for each statistica value (1 for UV, 1 for Folio and 1 for Promo)
and display the results in a separate memo for each. Hope I explained correctly, does it make sense?
I had a nightmare time trying to get this to work with teechart but apparently that can only group by either statistica or by date, not both.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is searching for records whose `statistica` value is **exactly** `'Folio'`, so all result records will have a `statistica` value of exactly `'Folio'`, thus grouping them by `statistica` is unnecessary.  Same thing if you do separate searches for `'UV'` and `'Promo'`.  If you want to group results by different `statistica` values, remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: To the downvoter without leaving a comment or an answer, you're really helpful dude. sheesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not extracting the first value of a result, only the second value.  And you are not looping through all available results, only looking at the first result.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Query.Close;
  Memo1.Clear;

  Query.SQL.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Query.SQL.Add('select date_format(data, ''%M-%Y'') as df, sum(pret) as test');
    Query.SQL.Add('from arhivalux');
    Query.SQL.Add('where statistica=''Folio''');
    Query.SQL.Add('group by statistica, year(data), month(data)');
  finally
    Query.SQL.EndUpdate;
  end;

  Query.Open;
  try
    while not Query.Eof do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Query.FieldByName('df').AsString + ' = ' + Query.FieldByName('test').AsString);
      Query.Next;
    end;
  finally
    Query.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hey Remy, now it's only showing the last value, 5017. Rechecking code now to see if I messed something up

Comment: That is because the code is setting the entire `Memo.Text` on each loop iteration, so only the last result will remain.  I have updated the example.

Comment: Also, would like to thank you for helping out with this. I'll be sure to search for further reading on this as I now know what to search for. Thanks!